# Always display full list of tools in the (Infragistic's) Toolbar

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I use some UltraToolbars in a form, and that toolbars fills all the upper space of the form, almost all of them are "truncated" - not all toolbars buttons are visible.

[image]

For the most toolbars this is not a problem, but for ones I'd like to always display all items. Is it possible to say to the UltraToolbar do not "truncate"(hide) its items (when docked).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Priority property might help?

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.SharedProps~Priority.html

If there's not enough room to show all the tools then some will have to be hidden, but that lets you pick which ones are more likely to be shown.

Otherwise I'd suggest docking the toolbar on a separate line to the other tool bars or break things up a little with some PopUpMenu tools.